# How do I record my screen, encode it to HEVC and then plug it into webrtc for streaming using aiortc-python

Tags: python-3.x, aiortc

I am trying to build a low-latency streaming software but I couldn't find a good way to record and encode the video into H.264/HEVC and also on how we plug all that into an [aiortc](https://aiortc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) stream.
I thought I would use FFMPEG for screen capture and encoding but that too, I couldn't find any guide for streaming through aiortc.

I realize this would be the entire project, but, like I said I couldn't find any good guides on this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit: I got it to capture and encode using [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python), but I still can't figure out how to pass it over webrtc.
I tried to pass it to the MediaPlayer function in aiortc, but that doesn't give any output on the webpage.

I edited the webcam.py code from the example on aiortc github repo, like below:

```
if args.play_from:
        process = (
            ffmpeg
            .input(format='gdigrab', framerate=60, filename="desktop")
            .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
            .run(capture_stdout=True)
        )

        video = (
            np
            .frombuffer(process, np.uint8)
        )

        player = MediaPlayer(video)
```

How will I get that to stream over aiortc?

Answer (score 0):

[webrtc-remote-screen](https://github.com/rviscarra/webrtc-remote-screen) is the only feature complete project I know of. I bet you can rip the capture code out of that and port to aiortc.

Rafael also wrote a blog post [here](https://viscarra.dev/post/webrtc-remote-screen/) on it.

Comment: That looks like a good guide. I'll certainly try to port that over to aiortc.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the program and any help would be fantastic!

Comment: I've got the ffmpeg-python to capture and encode the stream but still can't figure out how to stream it over aiortc. I tried passing it to pc.addTrack() too.